# Efficient way to remove FOLDER and FILES

Tags: php

I Use this function to remove a folder and its contents, i no have subdirectories in this folder, only files.

```
  $uploaddir = "DRIVE_LETTER/path/to/folder";
  $dir_contents = scandir($uploaddir);

  if(is_dir($uploaddir)) {
  foreach($dir_contents as $content) {
  unlink($uploaddir.'/'.$content);
  rmdir($uploaddir);
  }
 }
```

When i run script Warning appears, like this:

```
Warning: unlink(D:/path/2016-05-18/08/.) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\htdocs\test.php on line 32

Warning: rmdir(D:/path/2016-05-18/08) [function.rmdir]: Directory not empty in C:\htdocs\test.php on line 33

Warning: unlink(D:/path/2016-05-18/08/..) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\htdocs\test.php on line 32

Warning: rmdir(D:/path/2016-05-18/08) [function.rmdir]: Directory not empty in C:\htdocs\test.php on line 33
```

Instead warning, directory and files are removed, but, exist a more efficient way to remove folder and content?

Comment: You can't access other drive, but your server files

Comment: Instead warnings, i can delete folder located in another drive

Answer (score 1):

you have file permission problem which stop you to `unlink` files and folders try to change file permission using `chmod` and then remove files and folders

```
function chmod_r($path) {
  $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
  foreach ($dir as $item) {
     chmod($item->getPathname(), 0644);
     if ($item->isDir() && !$item->isDot()) {
        chmod_r($item->getPathname());
     }
   }
  chmod($path, 0644);
}

chmod_r('files');
$files = glob('files/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
  unlink($file); // delete file
}

rmdir("files");
```

this is an example which change permission of the file to remove.

in this there is a folder with the php script and a folder with files name and contain files with no delete permission. this first change permission of files and folders to 0644 // Read and write for owner, read for everybody else then remove files.

Comment: "Plus one" for using DirectoryIterator()

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
$uploaddir = "DRIVE_LETTER/path/to/folder";
  $dir_contents = scandir($uploaddir);
   $filename = 'Filename.jpg'; // Your file name
  if(is_dir($uploaddir)) {
  foreach($dir_contents as $content) {
  unlink("DRIVE_LETTER/path/to/folder".$filename);
  rmdir($uploaddir);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
function rrmdir($dir) { 
      foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
        if(is_dir($file)) rrmdir($file); else unlink($file); 
      } rmdir($dir); 
    }
    rrmdir("E:/testing")
```